# ERROR-ITMS 90534 "Invalid Toolchain "

Tags: ios, xcode

> ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds."

I am facing this issue while uploading to the appstore. I am using xcode8.3 can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: You are using beta XCode. Use the public version to upload apps.

Comment: Thanks i changed from beta to public version it is worked for me thanks iYoung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error since you are using **beta** version of XCode, to avoid this error, use **public version** of XCode & this error will be resolved.